# Failure to run Toolbelt on Windows 7 — invalid argument 'heroku-cli.exe'

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Just started digging into Heroku and I downloaded and installed Toolbelt with no problems (full install).

When I attempt to run any command however, I receive the following error:

```
$ heroku login

Invalid argument - "C:\Users\Veix\AppData\Local/heroku/heroku-cli.exe" version
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:107:in ``'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:107:in `version'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:213:in `check_if_old'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:123:in `setup'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'

Invalid argument - "C:\Users\Veix\AppData\Local/heroku/heroku-cli.exe" commands --json
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:87:in ``'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:87:in `commands_info'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:59:in `commands'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:208:in `find_command'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:12:in `try_takeover'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:25:in `start'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'

 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

Error:       Invalid argument - "C:\Users\Veix\AppData\Local/heroku/heroku-cli.exe" commands --json (Errno::EINVAL)
Command:     heroku login
Version:     heroku/toolbelt/3.42.20 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3


More information in C:/Users/Veix/.heroku/error.log
```

I'm running 64-bit Windows 7. I have a 64-bit version of Git (2.5.2.2) installed and also tried against the default x86 1.9.5 version that came with the installation, but without luck.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue happen on my machine. I went into the `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\heroku` directory and tried manually running `heroku-cli.exe` and got the error: `This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.`.

It turns out that the IT here has a group policy setup to block any executables from being run from the AppData directory. A quick fix for this was to copy the contents of the `%appdata%\Local\heroku` directory to my `c:\heroku`.

This will allow the program to execute but it then downloads the update for heroku back to the `AppData` directory again. To fix this I created a junction via cmd prompt in the `%appdata%\Local` to point to `c:\heroku`. The command is as follows:

```
cd C:\Users\USERNAMEHERE\AppData\Local
mklink /J heroku c:\heroku
```

You will see a confirmation like this:

```
Junction created for heroku <<===>> c:\heroku
```

Now you should be able to run the heroku tool-belt CLI.

Comment: Better late than never, but...thanx a ton.